# Подтянуть данные из таблицы на главную страницу сайта

Tags: php, html, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет! Есть вот такой сайт https://livehogwarts.ru/  с изображением часов на главной странице (в виде рисунка).

[image: Часы]

Так же есть табличка на https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...., откуда берутся цифры из 4 ячеек.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы эти цифры подтягивались из гугл таблицы автоматически при изменении ячеек? Или подскажите, в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Ну, не понятно через что всё это реализовано и как сейчас работает. Больше подробностей о том, что именно не работает в процессе разработки - не помешает

Comment: я бы начал с этого https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts?hl=ru